# Command to get the error in SFTP

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sftp

Can any one tell me how to get the error happened during file transfer using SFTP.
Is there any command to get the error in SFTP during file transfer? I am transfering some 10 files using SFTP. Suppose i got error while transfering 9th file, how to get the error and the file name which caused error in SFTP?

Comment: Have a look in /var/log/xferlog

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the sftp STDOUT/STDERR to log file (using > logfile 2>&1 ) where can be parsed to look for error if any. The good part is that sftp return non-zero only if there was any error during the session else it return zero.

```
# for batch mode
# will return zero if there was no error while executing commands in sftpcommand.txt file
sftp -b sftpcommand.txt user@server > /tmp/sftp.log 2>&1
sftp_return=$?  
if [ $sftp_reutrn -ne 0 ];
then
   echo "Some error during sftp ... check /tmp/sftp.log file"
else
   echo "No error during sftp"
fi
```